# Sets the value of a configuration option in Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I am trying to convert a php application to a ROR one. Php has ini_set, which sets the value of a configuration option. How can I do this in ROR.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_NONE);
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

Answer (score 2):

So Rails has the notion of different environments. Usually 3(production, development and test), They each come with their own config files.

You will find something like: `consider_all_requests_local` in those files. That is kind of the equivalent.

AFAIK there is no direct translation of ini_set into Ruby.